# Dynamic data is not updated in a ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm using the ngTable directive and the problem is that the data doesn't refresh in the table.

When loading the page, the gemId is undefined and no data shows which is ok.

Then you select a value from a dropdown and when pressing a button the loadItems function is called. Data is retrieved from the server but does not show in the table.
When I filter a column, the data is shown (= 2nd request ).

```
 $scope.tblProject = new ngTableParams(tableParameters, {
    counts: [], // hide page counts control
    total: $scope.items.length,  // value less than count hide pagination
    //defaultSort: ['asc','desc'];
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        //opgelet: request is geldig ondanks de onbestaand igeID;
        var gemId = modelFactory.getGemeente().id;
        var igeId = 22222;

        if(!angular.isUndefined(gemId)){
            Project.query({gemId: gemId, igeId: igeId}, function (projecten) {
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(projecten, params.orderBy()) : projecten;
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

            });
        }
    },
    $scope: { $data: {} } //see example 14
});


 $scope.$on('loadItems',function() {
    $scope.tblProject.reload();
});
```

Tried all the possible work-arounds for refreshing the table so far, but have had no luck.

edit: I think it is a scope problem when executing the 'loadItems'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was sending an event from the parentController to the childController using $emit instead of $broadcast which executes 'loadItems'